# solaris how identified which nfs client are mounting a share

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

We have a solaris nfs server and we have a share that was shared to everyone, now i would like to know which clients are mounting this share, on linux i can use showmount -a nfsserver, but on solaris showmount doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Solaris is not Linux.  Linux is not UNIX.  Solaris is UNIX.

Having said that :

```
$ dfmounts
RESOURCE     SERVER PATHNAME                  CLIENTS
  -            nfssvr /export/bootfs          192.168.35.214,nfsclient
```

So use dfmounts.

Comment: but this command need to be given on nfs server or on the client? because  i have a solaris 10 cluster with a nfs server share clustered but i didn' see any output